# Convertir ciclo For de Matlab a Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, matlab

Tengo este ciclo for de matlab pero quiero transformarlo a python, se encuentran agregadas las constantes del código:

```
%Metodo Piece Wise Exact

wn=20; %[rad/s]
m=0.1; %[kg]
z=0.02; %[-]
xo=0.001; %[m]
vo=0.2; %[m/s]
Fo=1; %[N]
om=10; %[rad/s]
wd=wn*sqrt(1-z^2); %[rad/s]
k=m*wn^2; %[kg*rad/s]
Be=om/wn; 
c=0;
fi=atan((c*om)/(k-m*om^2));

dt=0.001; %[s]
t=0:dt:4; %[s]

a=(exp(-z*wn*dt))*((z/sqrt(1-z^2))*sin(wd*dt)+cos(wd*dt));
b=exp(-z*wn*dt)*((1/wd)*sin(wd*dt));
c=(1/k)(((2*z)/(wn*dt))+exp(-z*wn*dt)(((1-2*z^2)/(wd*dt)-z/sqrt(1-z^2))*sin(wd*dt)-(1+((2*z)/(wn*dt))*cos(wd*dt))));
d=(1/k)(1-((2*z)/(wn*dt))+(exp(-z*wn*dt))(((2*z^2-1)/(wd*dt))*sin(wd*dt)+((2*z)/(wn*dt))*cos(wd*dt)));
A=-exp(-z*wn*dt)*((wn/sqrt(1-z^2))*sin(wd*dt));
B=exp(-z*wn*dt)*(cos(wd*dt)-(z/sqrt(1-z^2))*sin(wd*dt));
C=(1/k)(-(1/dt)+exp(-z*wn*dt)((wn/sqrt(1-z^2)+z/(dt*sqrt(1-z^2)))*sin(wd*dt)+(1/dt)*cos(wd*dt)));
D=(1/(k*dt))(1-exp(-z*wn*dt)((z/sqrt(1-z^2))*sin(wd*dt)+cos(wd*dt)));

f=Fo.*cos(om.*t);
U=(xo);
Up=(vo);
for i=1:length(t)-1
    U(:,i+1)=a*U(:,i)+b*Up(:,i)+c*f(:,i)+d*f(:,i+1);
    Up(:,i+1)=A*U(:,i)+B*Up(:,i)+C*f(:,i)+D*f(:,i+1);
end
```

Aquí el código de Python:

```
t=np.arange(0,5,0.001)
wn=20 #[rad/s]
m=0.1 #[kg]
Fo=1 #[N]
xo= 0.001
x_punto=0.2
zeta=0.02
k=m*(wn**2)
omega=10 #[rad/s]
beta=omega/wn
wd=wn*((1-zeta**2)**0.5)
cc=2*(m*k)**0.5
c=zeta*cc

phi=np.arctan(c*omega/(k-(m*omega**2)))

A=np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((zeta/((1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t)+np.cos(wd*t))
B=np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(np.sin(wd*t)/wd)
c1=(((1-2*zeta**2)/(wd*t)-(zeta/(1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t)-((1+2*zeta)/(wn*t))*np.cos(wd*t))
C=(1/k)*((2*zeta/(wn*t))+np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(c1))
D=(1/k)*(1-(2*zeta/(wn*t))+np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((2*zeta*2-1/(wd*t))*np.sin(wd*t)+(2*zeta/(wn*t))*np.cos(wd*t)))

a=-np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((wn/((1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t))
b=np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(np.cos(wd*t)-(zeta/((1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t))
c=(1/k)*((-1/t)+np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((wn/((1-zeta**2)**0.5)+(zeta/(t*((1-zeta**2)**0.5)))*np.sin(wd*t)+(1/t)*np.cos(wd*t))))
d=(1/k*t)*(1-np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(zeta/((1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t)+np.cos(wd*t))

F=Fo*np.cos(omega*t)
u = np.zeros(len(t)-1)
up = np.zeros(len(t)-1)
F = np.zeros(len(t)-1)
u[0]=xo
up[0]=x_punto

for  i in range(len(t)):
     u[i+1]=A*u[i]+B*up[i]+C*F[i]+D*F[i+1]
    up[i+1]=a*u[i]+b*up[i]+c*F[i]+d*F[i+1]
```

Los valores de las constantes se encuentran agregados al inicio del código.
Pero tengo problemas al correrlo ya que me aparece un error: "line 88, in 
u[i+1]=A*u[i]+B*up[i]+C*F[i]+D*F[i+1]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.". Qué correcciones necesito para la sección del ciclo For.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega las variables que hacen falta para que tu código pueda ser probado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya se están agregadas las constantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Es posible que al intentar traducir tu código de matlab a python y cambiado el nombre de las variables tal vez asignaste alguna `u` en lugar de `U` o algo similar

Si deseas refactorizar el código (Renombrar las variables) lo más recomendable es primero hacerlo funcionar tal y como está y luego refactorizar

Al respetar todas las variables tal y como aparecen en tu código de matlab el código no devuelve ningún error

**Nota:** Hay una línea donde en matlab se declara una multiplicación elemento por elemento, el método correspondiente en numpy sería `np.multiply()` pero numpy soporta multiplicación elemento por elemento por lo que utilizar cualquiera de las siguientes líneas daría el mismo resultado

```
f = np.multiply(Fo, np.cos(np.multiply(om,t)))
f = Fo*np.cos(om*t)
```

Pero de todas formas por favor compruebalo

Otra cosa, en el código que pusiste de python los rangos de `u`, `up` y del ciclo `for` están mal, no corresponden a lo que está en `matlab`

Código traducido:

```
import numpy as np

wn = 20
m = 0.1
z = 0.02
xo = 0.001
vo = 0.2
Fo = 1
om = 10
wd = wn * np.sqrt(1 - z**2)
k = m * wn**2
Be = om / wn 
c = 0
fi = np.arctan((c * om) / (k - m * om**2))

dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0,5,0.001)

a = (np.exp(-z*wn*dt))*((z/np.sqrt(1-z**2))*np.sin(wd*dt)+np.cos(wd*dt))
b = np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*((1/wd)*np.sin(wd*dt));
c = (1/k)*(((2*z)/(wn*dt))+np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*(((1-2*z**2)/(wd*dt)-z/np.sqrt(1-z**2))*np.sin(wd*dt)-(1+((2*z)/(wn*dt))*np.cos(wd*dt))))
d = (1/k)*(1-((2*z)/(wn*dt))+(np.exp(-z*wn*dt))*(((2*z**2-1)/(wd*dt))*np.sin(wd*dt)+((2*z)/(wn*dt))*np.cos(wd*dt)))
A = -np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*((wn/np.sqrt(1-z**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))
B = np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*(np.cos(wd*dt)-(z/np.sqrt(1-z**2))*np.sin(wd*dt))
C = (1/k)*(-(1/dt)+np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*((wn/np.sqrt(1-z**2)+z/(dt*np.sqrt(1-z**2)))*np.sin(wd*dt)+(1/dt)*np.cos(wd*dt)))
D = (1/(k*dt))*(1-np.exp(-z*wn*dt)*((z/np.sqrt(1-z**2))*np.sin(wd*dt)+np.cos(wd*dt)))

f = np.multiply(Fo, np.cos(np.multiply(om,t)))
#f = Fo*np.cos(om*t) Comprueba si esta línea te da el mismo resultado que la anterior

U = np.zeros(len(t))
Up = np.zeros(len(t))

U[0] = xo
Up[0] = vo


for i in range(1,len(t)-1):
    U[i+1] = a*U[i] + b*Up[i] + c*f[i] + d*f[i+1]
    Up[i+1] = A*U[i]+B*Up[i] + C*f[i] + D*f[i+1]
```

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias. Con las indicaciones que me diste me funcionó el código.

Comment: @Daniel, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)